# Temperature rise due to friction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I have 2 surfaces rubbing against one another (sliding past ) with some relative speed $v$ w.r.t. one another. Suppose, they slide for time $t$, like so. Is there then some formula for finding out, what would be the temperature rise in each of the surfaces in contact ?

My best guess is : $$\Delta T = \frac{K \cdot f \cdot v \cdot t}{S}$$
Where $K$ is a constant, $f$ is the frictional force and $S$ the specific heat capacity of the materials we choose.

Comment: Fourier's law over the WHOLE body is not necessasarily valid here. Think of it as...... Does whole of ice melt while rubbing our hand against one of its surface .

Answer (score 1):

The question is quite complicated due to several factors that come into play. Say a smaller body was sliding over the surface of a (very) large body. Temperature measured at a particular point in the larger body will change with time, as the smaller sliding body approaches/recedes from it. To avoid this complication, let us switch to the reference frame in which the smaller body is at rest, and in this frame, larger body will be sliding past the smaller one. Even in this reference frame, initially the temperature within the smaller body at a given point on or inside it, will not be a constant in time. Initially it begins with the ambient temperature $T_{ambient}$ and increases with time. As heat is produced due to sliding friction, it conducts through both the bodies, and is lost through convection and radiation to ambient. It seems reasonable to assume that if the body is sliding with constant velocity then, after a large enough time, a steady state temperature distribution will be reached both for the smaller body and the larger body (in this particular reference frame). Even in steady state, the temperature is not spatially uniform; in particular, temperature over the contact surface will not be uniform. So let us simplify matters even more by assuming that the contact surface is small enough for the temperature to be nearly uniform over the contact surface, and call it $T_{contact}$.

The heat flux at the contact surface equals the rate at which work is being done against friction: $Q=\mathbf{F}\cdot \mathbf{v}$. This heat flux goes into both the bodies. This is analogous to a current flowing through two parallel resistances: $Q$ is the current, $R_{small},R_{large}$, are (thermal) resistances of the smaller and larger body respectively (which are in parallel), $T_{contact}$ is the voltage at one end and $T_{ambient}$ is the voltage at the other end. Now we can estimate $\Delta T\equiv T_{contact}-T_{ambient}$ for limits such as $R_{small}\ll R_{large}$ or $R_{small}\gg R_{large}$. Say $R_{small}\ll R_{large}$, which can happen if the thermal conductivity of the smaller body is much higher than that of the larger body *and* if sliding velocity is small enough. The latter condition is necessary because if the sliding velocity is large, then smaller body slides onward to the cooler region of the larger body before it has had the opportunity to heat up. If $L_{small}$ is the characteristic length of the smaller body, then in the present case of $R_{small}\ll R_{large}$, we require that the Peclet number, $vL_{small}/\alpha_{small}$, where $\alpha_{small}$ is the thermal diffusivity of the smaller body, be small enough. Now $R_{small}$ is a function of $L_{small}$ and thermal conductivity $k_{small}$, and dimensional analysis gives you $R_{small}\sim L_{small}/k_{small}$, where constant of proportionality is presumably close to one. Then $\Delta T\sim Q R_{small}\sim Q  L_{small}/k_{small}$. It is much more difficult to figure out $R_{large}$, for the general case of arbitrary sliding velocities. However for large sliding velocities (more correctly, for large Peclet number defined before), $\Delta T\approx 0$.

While I do not offer a ready formula to calculate $\Delta T$ for arbitrary case, I hope my answer gives you a fruitful start; more importantly, I hope you appreciate the various complications hidden in your question.

Answer (score 1):

For the case of two identical semi-infinite slabs, if the normal stress is $\sigma$, the rate of heat generation per unit area of the boundary is $\sigma \mu v$, where v is the relative velocity and $\mu$ is the coefficient of friction.  Half this generated heat goes into one slab, and the other half goes into the other.  So the heat flux into each slab is $$q=\frac{\sigma \mu v}{2}$$ Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot (Transport Phenomena, problem 12B.3) give the temperature at the wall as a function of time for constant wall heat flux into a semi-infinite slab as:  $$T-T_0=\frac{q}{k}\sqrt{\frac{4\alpha t}{\pi}}$$where $T_0$ is the initial temperature, $q$ is the heat flux at the wall, k is the thermal conductivity, and $\alpha$ is the thermal diffusivity.  If we combine these two equations, we obtain:  $$T-T_0=\sigma \mu v\sqrt{\frac{ t}{\pi k \rho C}}$$ where $\rho$ is the density and C is the heat capacity.  So the temperature at the interface rises as the square root of time.

Comment: Only one qualifier: When applied to finite bodies, your proposed solution would be accurate only for small times $\ll\alpha^2/L$, where $\alpha$ is thermal diffusivity and $L$ is characteristic length of the body.

Comment: Sorry, it should be $L^2/\alpha$.

Comment: Yes.  That's, of course, correct.